# Check if an element has a background-image with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

What is the correct way to check if a particular element has a `background-image` associated with it, in pure Javascript?

Right now I have this:

```
var elementComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(element); 
var hasBGImage = elementComputedStyle.getPropertyValue('background-image') !== 'none'
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have works, but there are alternate ways of finding the property that you might find easier. I don't believe there is a single 'correct' way to do it, however.

Just javascript:

```
var hasBGImage = element.style.backgroundImage !== '';
```

Using jQuery:

```
var hasBGImage = $(element).css('background-image') !== 'none';
```

Comment: That would just check if the backgroundImage is applied inline. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare the background image "inline", otherwise .style.backgroundImage won't work.

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {
    var bg = document.getElementById('el').style.backgroundImage.length!=0;
    alert(bg);
}
</script>
<div id='el' style="background-image: url('a.jpg');"></div>
```

If you can use inline CSS, that's the way. If, for some reason, you can't use that, let me know, I'll try to find out something else :)

Comment: I am actually not doing this in my own site. I am parsing other sites, and the background-image is not always going to be inline.

Comment: I'm assuming you're working on some user script, is that correct? Can I ask you why jQuery is not an option, while I try to figure some other way?

Comment: Anyway, getComputedStyle() works just fine if you use window.onload; the only problem you would have is that IE<=8 doesn't support it. If you don't really care about that, go for it!

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in last one project and works perfect

```
    // Check all background images exists
var imageURLs = $('.image-container ');
imageURLs.each(function(index, element){
    var imageURL = $(element).css('background-image').replace('url("', '').replace('")', '');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onerror = function() { $(element).css('background-image','url(/build/images/missing-image.svg)'); };
    img.src = imageURL;
});
```