# Append style from selected element to another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a span element that dynamically changes based on the selected color:

`<span class="color checked" style="background-color: #ff0000">Red</span>`

I have an image element too without class:

```
<img id="image-png" src="myimage.png">
```

Now I want to append the background-color style and value to image from 'checked' span element. How can be done with JS ?

Comment: DOM manipulation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents
although i recommend using React or angularJS for a more robust solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const span = document.querySelector('span.checked');
const img = document.querySelector('#image-png');

img.style.backgroundColor = span.style.backgroundColor;
```

Comment: Is it possible to check if the span got a background image too:  <span class="color checked tex" style="background-image: url(path.jpg)" ? If it's a background image or a color background-color

Comment: sure you can find answers for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190468/check-if-an-element-has-a-background-image-with-pure-js